# How to connect front-page.php to page in admin panel?

Tags: frontpage

I need to make static front page of the site. I created file front-page.php and now my site first of all loads front-page.php as I needed, but how I can connect front-page.php to for example "Home" page in WP admin panel? So client can change content of Home page in admin panel?

Comment: A custom page template is more suitable in this case, why don't you try that?

Answer (score 0):

create a new template in your theme directory and call it `home-page.php`

Within that template place the following in at the start of the php file (remove the php tags if necessary):

```
<?php
/**
*
* Template Name: Home Page Template
*
*/
```

Copy and paste your code from front-page.php after these lines and save. Once that is done and there are no errors go into your admin area and you should be able to see a template available on the right hand side of the admin area when editing the home page.